# Connect phpmyadmin docker container to mysql container via network

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I have a first container with mysql and I have configured à volume to save data :

```
docker run --rm --name some-mysql --network mynet -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v %cd%\mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql`
```

And a phpmyadmin container :

```
docker run -d --rm --name pma --network mynet -p 8080:80 -e PMA_HOST=some-mysql -e UPLOAD_LIMIT=128M phpmyadmin
```

When I connect to localhost:8080 and try to connect with root/password he says "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3'"

When I don't add a volume to mysql container, it works fine ! So may I say somehow to the pma container where to find data ? I have tried to add the same  volume to the pma container, but it does not work...

Comment: Have you created the `mynet`  bridge network network prior this commands? If you don't please use https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

Comment: I have created the network

Comment: Did you try to wrap the volume path with "path", maybe the command breaks because of the escape characters